# A list contains another list with repetition

Tags: python, list, contains

I need to check if a list contains every element of another list in python. Not the set operation exactly, because in set distinct values are considered. How can I do it?

Sample:
a is the larger list, b is the smaller set

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 4], b = [1, 2, 3] -> False
a = [1, 1, 2, 3], b = [1, 2, 3] -> True
a = [1, 2, 4], b = [1, 2, 1] -> False // Because b has two 1s but a has only one.
```

I would like to request you to look at the third case carefully.

**[N. B.]** I know exactly how it can be done through hash map. But I want something less bulky.

Comment: @Blender Unfortunately this doesn't work. `Counter( [1, 1] ) <= Counter( [1, 2] )` evaluates to `True`. Presumably because `Counter.__sub__` keeps only positive counts.

Comment: @svk: Ah, you're right. I thought there was some overloaded operator that lets you do this, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: any option of multiset is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple one-liner with `Counter`

```
def isin(a, b): return not (Counter(b) - Counter(a))
```

Demo:

```
>>> isin([1, 1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3])
False
>>> isin([1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
True
>>> isin([1, 1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 1])
True
>>> isin([1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 1])
False
```

Comment: +1 It's so simple, elegant and now I understand why there is no need for `>=`

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter

def is_contained(a,b):
    aCount = Counter(a)
    bCount = Counter(b)
    return all(aCount[x] >= bCount[x] for x in bCount)



>>> is_contained([1, 1, 2, 4],[1, 2, 3])
False
>>> is_contained([1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
True
>>> is_contained([1, 2, 4],  [1, 2, 1])
False
```

Comment: How bad can it be? Any idea about the time complexity?

Comment: So far so good. Tested for some case. I would let you know if problem happens again. BTW any option of multiset is available?

Comment: if performance is an issue, maybe this is little faster `all(aCount[x] >= bcountx for x, bcountx in bCount.iteritems() )`. +1 for using Counter...

Comment: @Md.TaufiqueHussain The counter solution is O(n) which is best possible in this case.

Comment: @DhruvPathak I did some further research on Counter-Class and it provides intersections. So you can use `return aCount & bCount == bCount` in your function.

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter

def is_contained(a, b):
    aCount = Counter(a)
    bCount = Counter(b)
    # think of it as aCount >= bCount in set-operations
    return aCount & bCount == bCount
```

Comment: Very elegant, I like it.

Comment: It worked but I am new in python. So please be kind enough explain it. BTW what is the complexity here? Looks like O(1) but that would depend on Counter() and I don't know exactly what it does.

Comment: You can get more information at [Counter-Documentation.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) That line first builds an intersection of both Counters, which means for every counted key in both Counters it takes minimum of occurrences. And if a contains b, this Counter-intersection (or call it minimum) has to be `bCount`.
Compare it to this `set`-statement: `setA & setB == setB` means the same as `setB <= setA`. `Counter` has no proper `<=`-implementation, so I had to take an other approach.

Comment: @koffein counters can be added, see example in my answer

Comment: @alko Yes, I see. I thought about subtracting aCount - bCount and then look for negative "values", but I did not thought of bCount - aCount… Spent some time thinking, but did not thought of the easiest one…

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question, which was closed with a reference to this one. The problem I have with these answers is that they all create a Counter object from the lists. Unless I am misunderstanding something, that is essentially creating a duplicate of both the full and the sub list. This is unimportant if both are small but if you're dealing with large lists, that's inefficient. I went with this:

```
def is_valid_sub(full_list, sub_list):
    matched = []
    for sub_item in sub_sublist:
        for indx, full_item in enumerate(full_list):
            if sub_item == full_item and indx not in matched:
                matched.append(indx)
                break
    return len(matched) == len(sub_list)
```

Edit: Added more meaningful variable names

Comment: you should give meaningful names to your variables, it's not too clear otherwise...

Answer (score -2):

def contains(a,b):
    for item in set(a):
        if item in set(b):
            print 'something or do something'

Comment: Look I mentioned that set operation is not what I want.